# SignalR is manipulating updates when clients are connected and doing manipulation simultaneously

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

When two connected clients add data simultaneously, signalR give wrong updates.
Like  Clients.Caller.myProgram() is called after adding one record. It show that this record is entered by someone else.
After refreshing page, it shows correctly.
This happens only when two clients add record simultaneously. 
I am using  Clients.Caller.myProgram() and Clients.Others.otherProgram() to send new added record

Comment: You should show your client and server side code. The way you state the problem it could be many things, including bugs on your side.

Comment: Clients.Caller.myProgram();

Clients.Others.otherProgram(); It is considering caller in "others"

Comment: That is not much :)  Normally people asking questions here put much more code that that. The phrase *It show that this record is entered by someone else* implies a lot of things: a *record*, a place where you display info about that record, i.e. its creator, arguments passed to your callbacks, and so on... The phrase *After refreshing page, it shows correctly* again implies code which would be different from the one done on SignalR's callbacks. We do not see any of those, and there might be bugs there, it's difficult to help this way.